# Synchronize between processes?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-safety, synchronize

I have an Android program which has a RemoteService (different process) and the Application (with the UI). Now if I have a `synchronize` function used by both these components, will they be synchronized? Despite of the fact that both are in different processes?

Comment: "I have an Android program which has a RemoteService (different process) and the Application (with the UI). " -- why? An application typically runs in just one process.

Comment: @CommonsWare Because those two have different purposes, and the service's load cannot be shunted on the UI. Moreover those two programs don't share anything other than accessing a same Database.

Comment: If they are separate APKs for some reason, then you do not have "an Android program", you have two Android "programs". If you have one APK, please do not use multiple processes. All you do is waste RAM for no value. "the service's load cannot be shunted on the UI" -- I do not precisely understand this phrase, but this sounds like something threads will solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No - synchronize will not work across processes.

Comment: And there is no utility in them working across processes, since the processes do not share any state that would need to be synchronized.  A variable in one process will not have the same data as a variable in the other process.